# implementing cd system call using C- if condition

Tags: c, cd

Here is code that implements the cd system call using C. The problem with this code is that it's not entering the `if` condition  `if(strcmp(buffer,"cd") == 0)`
and I can't understand why.

```
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<dirent.h>
#include<error.h>

#define BUFFERSIZE 20
int main(){

char *args[80]; 
char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
char *prompt = "OS";
char *a = ">";
printf("%s%s",prompt,a); 
fgets(buffer, BUFFERSIZE, stdin);  

char *tok; 
tok = strtok (buffer," ");


while(buffer != NULL){ 
   buffer[strlen(buffer)-1] = '\0';  
   pid_t pid;
   pid = fork();
   if(pid < 0){
      fprintf(stderr, "Fork failed");
      return 1;
   }
   else if(pid == 0){

       if(strcmp(buffer,"cd") == 0){
         tok = strtok(NULL,"\n");
         cd(tok);
       }
       printf("%s%s",prompt,a); 
       fgets(buffer, BUFFERSIZE, stdin);
   }
   else{
     wait(NULL);
   }
}
return 0;
}


int cd(char *pth){
   char path[1000];
   strcpy(path,pth);

   static char *prompt = "OS";
   static char *a = ">";
   char *token;

   char cwd[256]; 
   getcwd(cwd,sizeof(cwd));

   strcat(cwd,"/"); 
   strcat(cwd,path);
   chdir(cwd);    

   printf("%s-%s%s",prompt,path,a);
   return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Q: Have you looked at the value of "temp" in your debugger of choice?  Is it in fact equal to "cd"?  Here's a good tutorial for "gdb": http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gilpin/tutorial/

Comment: 1) `buffer[strlen(buffer)-1] = '\0';` Bad habit, IMHO. strlen() *could* return zero. 2) `tok = strtok (temp," ");` tok shadows another `tok`

Comment: `cd` *can't* be a standalone program, it has to be a shell builtin.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: `cd` is a shell command; the system call is `chdir`. And your code doesn't *implement* `chdir`, it merely calls it.

Comment: Furthermore, `fgets()` returns the number of characters read *and* guarantees to NULL-terminate the buffer. 

Might also want to consider whether `while (buffer!=NULL)` can ever evaluate false, with `buffer` being on the stack?

Comment: actually what i am trying to do is that i am implementing cd(system call) using c programming. that is when the c program runs . it prints a prompt. user enter "cd XXX" and the C program then changes present directory to that directory(in this case XXX).

Comment: @wildplasser. i didnt get what you meant by overshadowing another tok.

Comment: @KeithThompson. yes my code isnt implementing chdir. it is implementing cd using in C using commands like chdir and getcwd etc.

Comment: @Marko. yeah i have been facing problem exiting the program. coz while condition is not getting false. what can i replace NULL with inorder to get out of the loop? should equate it to some variable? like this
int should_run == 1;
while(should_run){}
and to get out of the loop set should_run = -1
or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: @CarlNorum. cd is not a stand alone program it is a function. which i am calling in main function of my c program.

Comment: @user128806: Your title refers to "cd system call".  `cd` is not a system call.  That's my point.

Comment: @KeithThompson. apologies for that.

Comment: @user128806: there are two instances of `tok`: one outside the loop(never used) and one inside. That's the point where the confusion starts; not for the compiler (though it *could* warn), but for me.

Comment: @wildplasser..ooops sorry.. i have posted the editted code... but it still doesnt set if condition true..Y?

Comment: The if condition is never gonna get true because its in the child process! and you have not implemented any logic to pass the value to the child process. Further more why do you need a child process for this?

Comment: @bikram990 A child process is a copy of the parent process. All the variables are copied automatically, you don't need to pass them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have updated the logic after suggestions from others.

There is **no need for a child process** here. If you want multitasking then use threads. `Child process may be required for process running in background.`

The following program is working for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
//#include <error.h>

int hasPrefix(char const *, char const *);
int cd(char *pth);

#define BUFFERSIZE 200
int main(){

    char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
    char *prompt = "OS";
    char *a = ">";

    char *tok;
    tok = strtok (buffer," ");


    while(buffer != NULL){
        bzero(buffer, BUFFERSIZE);
        printf("%s%s",prompt,a);
        fgets(buffer, BUFFERSIZE, stdin);
        if(hasPrefix(buffer,"cd") == 0){
            tok = strchr(buffer,' '); //use something more powerful
            if(tok) {
                char *tempTok = tok + 1;
                tok = tempTok;
                char *locationOfNewLine = strchr(tok, '\n');
                if(locationOfNewLine) {
                    *locationOfNewLine = '\0';
                }
                cd(tok);
            }
        }else{
            system("ls"); //for testing the CWD/PWD
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int hasPrefix(char const *p, char const *q)
{
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0;q[i];i++)
    {
        if(p[i] != q[i])
            return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int cd(char *pth){
    char path[BUFFERSIZE];
    strcpy(path,pth);

    char cwd[BUFFERSIZE];
    if(pth[0] != '/')
    {// true for the dir in cwd
        getcwd(cwd,sizeof(cwd));
        strcat(cwd,"/");
        strcat(cwd,path);
        chdir(cwd);
    }else{//true for dir w.r.t. /
        chdir(pth);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the standard `strcmp()` that requires writing his own.

Comment: You should not have suggested using a homebrew `mystrcmp`, and you've inadvertently demonstrated just why. The standard `strcmp` has nothing wrong here, while yours does. It has two bugs: 1. If `q` is an empty string (`""`), you will always report equality and 2. If the string `p` has the string `q` as a prefix but has trailing additional characters, it will report equality. It would have been better to [chop off the newline from `fgets()` with this one-liner](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28462221/2809095).

Comment: @Barmar Its been 1 year since I looked on this. I don't remember why I said it. If `strcmp` is right for you then you can use it.

Comment: @DanielJour thanks for pointing out. I've updated the answer now.

Comment: @Barmar Actaully I wanted a `hasPrefix` method and named the method as `mystrcmp` and blamed the standard `strcmp`. Now realizing that How foolish I was to blame standard `strcmp`.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
...
if(strncmp(buffer,"cd",2) == 0){
...
```

instead. It is good for comparing prefixes of arbitrary length. It's also puts a limit on string size. No need to build your own comparison routine.

You have other problems elsewhere in the code, but those can be addressed separately.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is because of this line:

```
buffer[strlen(buffer)-1] = '\0';
```

This replaces the last character of `buffer` with a null character. So if `buffer` contained `"cd"`, it now contains just `"c"` (since the null character is the string terminator in C).

There doesn't seem to be any need for this statement, just remove it.

Comment: Just stumbled upon this, and this is really the only correct answer.